# Jquery redirect stopped working

Tags: jquery, redirect, href, window.location

I have a basic jquery modal window I use for messages, etc. its been working fine until the last 2 days. Ive tried hashing out code, and even a basic test isnt working.

here is the script:

```
              $(document).ready(function() {

              $("#dialog").html("Please login - redirecting...");

              $("#dialog").dialog({

                  autoOpen: true,
                  show: "fade",
                  hide: "fade",
                  modal: true,
                  open: function(event, ui) {

                      setTimeout(function(){
                          $("#dialog").dialog("close");                
                      }, 2000);

             }
              });

          $(function() {
              $("#dialog").dialog({
                  close: function(event, ui) { 

                    location.href = "login.php" }
              });
          });

           });
```

Any ideas?? I have looked at the window.location article and that also isnt working..

Answer (score 0):

Change `setTimeout` to `setInterval` as show below in `dialog.open` function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

          $("#dialog").html("Please login - redirecting...");
          $("#dialog").dialog({
              autoOpen: true,
              show: "fade",
              hide: "fade",
              modal: true,
              open: function(event, ui) {
                  setInterval(function(){
                      $("#dialog").dialog("close");                
                  }, 2000);
         }
          });

      $(function() {
          $("#dialog").dialog({
              close: function(event, ui) { 
                location.href = "login.php" }
          });
      });
       });
```

Comment: still doesnt work. the code used to work, i dont know what could have changed / stopped it.. I did some php coding etc..is my code valid??

Answer (score 0):

My bad - I had a phantom JS closing bracket elsewhere - first few times i tried hashing out code it must have been skipped or something - apologies.

Ill leave the script up here cos its a nice modal message window that disappears. Below is the php function:

```
function ModalRedir($msg,$redir,$ms){

if(!isset($ms)){
  $ms=800;
}

  if($redir !==0){
    $fwd='$(function() {
              $("#dialog").dialog({
                  close: function(event, ui) { location.href = "'.$redir.'" }
              });
          });';
  }
  else{
    $fwd='';
  }


  echo ' 

           <script>
          $( document ).ready(function() {

              $("#dialog").html("'.$msg.'");

              $("#dialog").dialog({

                  autoOpen: true,
                  show: "fade",
                  hide: "fade",
                  modal: true,
                  open: function(event, ui) {

                      setTimeout(function(){
                          $("#dialog").dialog("close");                
                      }, '.$ms.');

             }
              });

          '.$fwd.'

           });

          </script>

          <div id="dialog" style="display:none;">

          </div>

          ';
```

}

Simply run this:

```
echo ModalRedir('Please login - redirecting...','path/to/file(login.php)',ModalWait);
```

ModalWait is defined variable, mine is at 2000ms..